# Getting "Must have a uuid if no _objectID" exception when inserting object into dictionary

Tags: swift, dictionary, hashable

I'm writing a unit-test to a class that uses `PHAsset` type. I mocked it as below:

```
class PHAssetMock: PHAsset {
    let date: Date
    let uuid: UUID

    init(dateStr: String) {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"
        self.date = dateFormatter.date(from: dateStr)!
        self.uuid = UUID()
    }

    override var creationDate: Date? {
        return date
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        let hash = Int(self.date.timeIntervalSinceNow)
        return hash
    }


    static func ==(lhs: PHAsseMock, rhs: PHAsseMock) -> Bool {
        return lhs.date.timeIntervalSinceNow == rhs.date.timeIntervalSinceNow
    }
```

}

When a function that uses mocked objects tries to insert it in a dictionary I'm getting an exception:

```
func foo(assets: [PHAsset]) {
    var label: [T: String]()
    for asset in assets {
        label[asset] = "undefined" // Exception: "NSInternalInconsistencyException", "Must have a uuid if no _objectID"
    }
}
```

When debugging, the override hash var is being called.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue with the `PHAsset` when unit testing `Photos` framework. Overriding `isEqual` function helped to get rid of the exception.

```
class Mock : PHAsset {

    let _localIdentifier: String   = UUID().uuidString
    let _hash: Int                 = UUID().hashValue

    override var localIdentifier: String {
        return _localIdentifier
    }

    override var hash: Int {
        return _hash
    }

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        guard let object = object as? Mock else {
            return false
        }
        return self.localIdentifier == object.localIdentifier
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It helped me a lot, never though about subclassing it.